# M-estimation for regression

Tags: regression, robust, m-estimation

An M-estimator $(\beta,\sigma)$ is defined as the parameters that minimize
$$
\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n \rho\left(\dfrac{y_i -x_i^T \beta}{\sigma}\right)$$,
for some robust function $\rho$. I understand that typically it's going to bound the influence of an outlier (observation with outlying $y$-part). Then they introduce some weight functions that give a low weight for an observation with an outlying $x$-part and implement it into the $\rho$ function (GM estimation). But why is that needed in fact? Good leverage points follow the pattern of the gross of the data, so they are in fact not bad for estimating the regression parameters? So how are they bad for estimation $\beta$?

Comment: ...bad leverage points, that's who. [Example 4 here shows one such configuration](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/node/337).

Comment: "*Then they introduce...*" who is they? What are you looking at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linear least squares is optimal when the errors are distributed Normally, but can be far from optimal with other distributions, especially fat-tailed ones.  Fat-tailed distributions can arise for any number of reasons, outliers mixed in with "reasonable" errors being one of them.  Typically with fat-tailed distributions we'd prefer an objective function that doesn't put as much weight on data points / errors out in the tails of the distribution as least squares does, and in many cases we actually prefer objective functions that downweight more extreme data points to having weights close to zero.

A couple of examples of how poorly least squares can perform relative to an off-the-shelf robust estimator are below.

We assume a linear relationship of the form $y_i = \beta x_i + e_i$, where $e_i \text{ i.i.d. } t_3$, a Student-t variate with three degrees of freedom.  This distribution has much fatter tails than the Normal.  We generate 100 observations and estimate $\beta$ using least squares and a redescending estimator based on the [bisquare function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_statistics#M-estimators), repeat 1000 times, and see how accurate the two estimators are:

```
library(MASS)

beta_1 <- data.frame(ls=rep(0,1000), bisq=rep(0,1000))
for (i in 1:nrow(beta_1)) {
   x <- rnorm(100)
   y <- x + rt(100,3)
   beta_1$ls[i] <- lm(y~x)$coefficients["x"]
   beta_1$bisq[i] <- rlm(y~x, psi=psi.bisquare)$coefficients["x"]
}

apply(beta_1, 2, sd)
```

which gives us:

```
> apply(beta_1, 2, sd)
       ls      bisq 
0.1809239 0.1296139
```

showing that our off-the-shelf robust estimator has about 72% of the standard error of the least squares estimator.

One thing to note about this example: we don't have outliers in the traditional sense of erroneous data records or data points that are drawn from some other distribution than the assumed one, so, even with perfect knowledge of how each data point was generated, we wouldn't be able to delete the outlying data points - there really aren't any.

Now we'll generate our data using a model where there are some errors that can be thought of as outliers.  The errors are assumed Normally distributed with $\sigma = 1$, but a random 5% of them have an additional Normal error term with $\sigma = 5$ added to them.

```
beta_1 <- data.frame(ls=rep(0,1000), bisq=rep(0,1000))
for (i in 1:nrow(beta_1)) {
   x <- rnorm(100)
   y <- x + rnorm(100)
   z <- rbinom(100,1,0.05)
   y <- y + z*rnorm(100,0,5)
   beta_1$ls[i] <- lm(y~x)$coefficients["x"]
   beta_1$bisq[i] <- rlm(y~x, psi=psi.bisquare)$coefficients["x"]
}

> apply(beta_1, 2, sd)
       ls      bisq 
0.1518029 0.1147156
```

and our off-the-shelf robust estimator of $\beta$ now has about 75% the standard error of the least squares estimator.

In a very real sense, the distinction I've drawn between models with outliers and models without is much sharper than it should be; the issue is more fat tailed-error distributions, not so much how they get that way.  If you have some idea of how they got that way, you can craft better estimators, of course, but bounded influence / robust regression considered as a broad class of estimators and techniques for designing new estimators is designed to deal with fat tails in general, not outliers specifically.

Answer (score 2):

In linear regression, it is used when the error distribution is not normal due to the presence of outliers or bad values. The linear least-squares estimates of the regression parameters can behave badly when you have a lot of outliers (i.e. when the distribution of residuals has tails heavier than a normal distribution), and particularly so when the sample size is small. A single very large bad value may have a large, unwarranted influence on your estimated $\hat{\beta}$ (in fact the $\hat{\beta}$ can be made arbitrarily bad by changing the $y$-part of just a single observation to an arbitrarily large value). So if you are worried that a fraction of your data may consist of bad values, it makes sense to protect against these problematic data points.

If you are interested in a practical tutorial with examples on robust regression, I suggest [this one](http://users.stat.umn.edu/~sandy/courses/8053/handouts/robust.pdf) by John Fox